Maya Plugin Prefs Secure Loading
I need to disable secure loading of plugins before starting Maya (or add the path to the plugins to the trusted paths).
Expect: command or environment variable that allows you to disable secure plugin load, something like "cmds.pluginInfo(trusted=True)" Exclude adding path to plugins to MAYA_PLUG_IN_PATH

You should consider editing userPrefs.mel file
